# Nginx with Uwsgi throws 404 not found when accessing image in the ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have created a flask application and deployed it in a remote ubuntu server using Nginx and uwsgi. But I can't access images in the application folder. The images are stored in **/myproject/static/images/** folder.

Here is the server block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/root/myproject_sock/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

How can I access the images kept in  **/myproject/static/images/** folder through image URL i.e. HTTP://myip/myproject/static/images/first_image.jpg ?

Comment: what is the error you are getting in nginx error logs ?

Comment: Nginx is not serving any static files. If you want Nginx to serve static files you will need to add a `location` and `root` directive, for example: `location /myproject/static/images/ { root /; }`

Comment: @SouravAtta there is no error in the Nginx error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RichardSmith (https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith) the issue is solved.
If you are facing the same problem, you need to edit your server block inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject` (myproject can be anything you named your project earlier).

You need to add `location` and `root` directive. for example: `location /DIR_NAME/myproject/static/images/ { root /; }`. Here inside `DIR_NAME` you need to put the parent directory of your `myproject` folder.

Follow: http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html